# A problem regarding a maximal ideal in a polynomial ring in several variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Is the ideal $I =\langle x^2-2,y^2+1,z\rangle$ maximal in the polynomial ring $R =\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ ?

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Actually, by $3rd$ isomorphism theorem of rings, quotenting both $R$ and $I$ by $\langle z \rangle$, we get $\frac{R}{I} \cong \frac{\mathbb Q[x,y]}{\langle x^2-2 , y^2+1\rangle}$ ;

Now , if we define a map $\phi : \mathbb Q[x,y] \to \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$ where $i^2=-1;$ by $\phi(f(x,y)) = f(\sqrt 2,i)$ then can we show that kernel of this map is $J =\langle x^2-2,y^2+1\rangle$ ?

Here, one inclusion is obvious, but how about the other ?

I have tried a lot, but I can't prove it .
A small hint is warmly appreciated.

Comment: The given answer is fine, and directly answers your specific question about the kernel of $\phi$, but you could also continue the logic of your approach and check that (e.g.) $\mathbb{Q}[x, y]/\langle x^{2}-2 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]$, so you would then just need to check that $y^{2}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]$.

Comment: I have also thought in this way , but is it true that $\frac{J}{\langle x^2-2\rangle} \cong \langle y^2+1\rangle$ ? How about the linear terms of $y$ of a polynomial in $J$ ?

Comment: What sort of linear terms are you worried about? Every element of $J$ is expressible as $p(x, y)(x^{2}-2) + q(x, y)(y^{2}+1)$ for some $p, q \in \mathbb{Q}[x, y]$. The isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[x, y]/\langle x^{2} - 2 \rangle \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]$ sends $f(x, y)$ to $f(\sqrt{2}, y)$, and so $p(x, y)(x^{2}-2) + q(x, y)(y^{2}+1)$ gets sent to $q(\sqrt{2}, y)(y^{2}+1)$, which lives in the ideal generated by $y^{2}+1$.

Comment: Okay,okay, sorry I couldn't think the co-domain as $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)[y]$, I was thinking something else .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]=\mathbb{Q}[y][x]=\mathbb{Q}[x][y]$. Using long division by $x^2+1$, we get $f=q(x,y)(x^2+1)+r_1(y)+r_2(y)x$.
Now, divide $q$ and $r_1,r_2$ by $y^2-2$.

Comment: but I need to show that ker$\phi = J$ ? Here, the remainder polynomial is only $r(y)$, and not a multiple of $(y^2+1) .$

Comment: Read the hint carefully.  Divide $q$ and $r$ by $y^2-2$ .

Comment: How are you sure that the remainder $r(y)$ only consists polynomial in $y$, but not in $x$ and $y$ both ?

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're right, it was a misprint. I 've edited my answer.